# What is the best way to find is there any gap between number of ranges?

Tags: c#, linq

I am keeping staff clock-in times daily.
Sometimes they work the next day without taking any break.

WHAT I NEED IS
Without a break,the Total Hrs of staff who finish at midnight.

For example

| Staff | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Staff A | 9 AM | 3 PM |
| Staff A | 3 PM | 10 PM |
| Staff A | 10 PM | **12:00 AM** |
| Staff B | 3 AM | 9 PM |
| Staff B | 10 PM | **12:00 AM** |
| Staff C | 3 AM | 9 PM |
| Staff D | 10 PM | **12:00 AM** |

In the above table, both staffs finished at midnight.

Staff A worked **15hrs without any breaks.**
But Staff B had a break between **9 PM and 10 Pm.**

Expected result:

| Staff | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Staff A | 15 |
| Staff B | 2 |
| Staff C | 0 because he didn't finish at midnight. |
| Staff C | 2 |

I tried **for** loop, but it failed because each staff has a different number of entries, codes got messy at the end.

I tried LINQ and joining the same table etc. but couldn't figure it out.

This website is my last option.

Thanks advance for help.

Comment: What does it have to do with LINQ? This sounds like a common range joining problem: get all the time ranges for a person, combine them when they overlap/adjacent, then check whatever you want on what comes out of it.

Comment: Hi Nord, overlapping is easy to test. As you can see from the table, they are not overlapping. I can do with lots of for loop but i am sure there is a smarter way to do it

Comment: I think your second chart's 4th row 'Staff' column should be 'Staff D'

Comment: Could you add your table/entity structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this answer will need a bunch more work if you need this for work segments that cross dates or multiple dates. This assumes all work segments are in the same day.

The following groups all segments by staff, then adds up each segment total minutes. Then only returns the total if the last segment ends at midnight.

This test code returns the following:

```
Staff A: 15
Staff B: 20
Staff C: 0
Staff D: 2
```

Here's the code:

```
void Main()
{
    var segments = GetTestData();
    DateTime midnight = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;
    var results = segments
        .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
        .Select(grp => 
            new {
                Name = grp.Key, 
                Total = grp.Max(g => g.EndDate) == midnight 
                    ? grp.Sum(g => g.EndDate.Subtract(g.StartDate).TotalMinutes) 
                    : 0
            });

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{result.Name}: {result.Total/60F:#,##0}");
    }
}

class Segment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

Segment[] GetTestData()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new Segment { Name = "Staff A", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 9 , 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 15, 0, 0) },
        new Segment { Name = "Staff A", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 15, 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 22, 0, 0) },
        new Segment { Name = "Staff A", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 22, 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 19, 0 , 0, 0) },
        new Segment { Name = "Staff B", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 3 , 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 21, 0, 0) },
        new Segment { Name = "Staff B", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 22, 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 19, 0 , 0, 0) },
        new Segment { Name = "Staff C", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 3 , 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 21, 0, 0) },
        new Segment { Name = "Staff D", StartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 18, 22, 0, 0), EndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 19, 0 , 0, 0) }
    };
}
```